# Not able to remove hotkey using keyboard module of python3

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, hotkeys

I have declare `ctlr+shift+a` as hotkey using keyboard module.
`import keyboard`

`keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+a', print, args =('you entered', 'hotkey'))`

whenever this hotkey pressed, call a function or any statement like this code,

`while True:`

````
```if keyboard.read_hotkey():```

    ```print('hotkey pressed')```
````

but after executing this code it's **reset the all keyboard's button as hot key** and gives output like
`hotkey pressed` even pressed single key of keyboard.
so it's not working properly after that if I wish to remove this hotkey, so to do that I used this line of code.

`keyboard.remove_hotkey('ctrl+shift+a')`

but still also not working and to reset my keyboard I need to restart my system.
So *how to set the hotkey* and **remove** that hotkey??

Answer (score 3):

this will unhook all hotkeys

```
keyboard.unhook_all_hotkeys()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the while loop and you should stop the while loop.
Remove the while loop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).